# not_found is not working in Sinatra Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i have two urls i want to redirect users to one of those urls. i want users to get redirected if the first url will not work. Following is my code. Thank you for your support. The following code is not redirecting to the 2nd url when my first url is not working. Can you please tell what am i missing here.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

set :environment, :production
get '/jde' do

  redirect "url1"

end

not_found do
  redirect "url2"
end
```

Comment: both urls are https. thanks